# scrolling menu doesn't fully work

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I know AS2 is old but I don't know as3 well enough yet and i haven't touched AS2 in years as it is.

Here is my issue: I have two horizontal thumbnail scrolling menus (one on the left and one on the right). The one on the right works perfectly.

```
rightEdge = gmask._x;
maskWidth = gmask._width;
sliderWidth = gslider._width;
ratio = maskWidth / (sliderWidth - maskWidth - 55);
targX = gslider._x;

gslider.onEnterFrame = function() { 
    this._x += (targX - this._x) / 5;
}

gslider.onMouseMove = function() {  
    if (gmask.hitTest(_root._xmouse, _root._ymouse, false)) {
        targX = rightEdge - (gmask._xmouse / ratio);
        updateAfterEvent();
    }
}
```

I figured I could copy the code of the right one and just change the appropriate instances and vars but of course it's not that easy. I've spent hours trying different combinations but now i'm back at square one.

```
leftEdge = wmask._x + wmask._width;
maskWidth1 = wmask._width;
sliderWidth1 = wslider._width;
ratio1 = maskWidth1 / (sliderWidth1 - maskWidth1 - 55);
targX1 = wslider._x;

wslider.onEnterFrame = function() { 
    this._x += (targX1 - this._x) / 5;
}

wslider.onMouseMove = function() {  
    if (wmask.hitTest(_root._xmouse,_root._ymouse,false)) {
        targX1 = leftEdge - (wmask._xmouse / ratio1);
        updateAfterEvent();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is the current behavior and the expected one?

Comment: Also, as you didn't work with actionScript-2 for a while, I'd say it can be a good opportunity to start to learn actionscript-3.

Comment: I agree with duTr. If you're able to use AS3, you really should. It takes time to get a hang of, but the transition isn't all too difficult and you'll quickly realise how much better than AS2 it is.

Comment: sorry guys i'm new to this site and didn't see the other replies. this is my portfolio and i'm being turned down for jobs because i don't have this online. my plan was to hurry and get this online then once it can be seen i'll start rebuilding in AS3 and starting from there.
if you look at the reply i left on xxxeons comment there is a link that shows it as it all currently resides and a slight explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i finally got it. i know it may not be clean but this code works perfectly for the left side scroller.

```
leftEdge=wmask._x + wmask._width;
maskWidth1=wmask._width;
sliderWidth1=wslider._width;
ratio1=maskWidth1/(sliderWidth1-maskWidth1+15)
targX1=wslider._x;

wslider.onEnterFrame=function(){    
    this._x+=(targX1-this._x)/5;
}
wslider.onMouseMove=function(){ 
    if(wmask.hitTest(_root._xmouse,_root._ymouse,false)){
    targX1=(wmask._width*2+100)-(wmask._xmouse/ratio1);
    updateAfterEvent();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see that might not be right is this

leftEdge = wmask._x + wmask._width;

Should be ...
leftEdge = wmask._x;

If you are wanting to use an exact duplicate of the original.

Comment: that sends the wslider mc completely off the edge. a little more background to what i'm trying to do the gslider(right side) works perfectly here(http://ctxdesigns.net/slider.swf) and the left just goes crazy. but i need the left to start on the right side of the wmask and the ending point would be the left side. i don't know if that makes sense lol, but look at the right side as it does the complete opposite.